# Google AMP how to use private key to sign the update-cache request?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache#rsa-keys), it's mentioned

> Use the private key to sign the update-cache request. For example: echo -n >url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1484941817' cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem >signature.bin
>   The output to signature.bin is a binary RSA signature.

So, I'm expecting this command to generate a `signature.bin` file.

However, when I try to enter command `echo -n >url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/example.com/article?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1484941817' cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem >signature.bin`
 in my Windows command prompt I get the error:

> 'amp_ts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I'm now unsure where I should enter this command.

Comment: I see you're following Generate the RSA key guide. Did you jump straight to step 3 or did you start at 1?

Comment: I started at step 1. So I now have file `private-key.pem` and `public-key.pem`. I renamed `public-key.pem` to `apikey.pub` and made it available on my domain on `https://example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`. A file `url.txt` is created when I execute the command, which contains line `-n  '/update-cache/c/s/example.com/article?amp_action=flush`.